# Create a list prefab buttons in the script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a school project and have encountered the following issue.

I'm trying to create a gameboard made out of a prefab (the prefab is a button). For that I have the following code:

```
public GameObject tilePrefab;
public Transform newParent;
public int xAxis = 0;
public int yAxis = 0;
private int boardWidth = 9;
public int boardHeight = 5;


private void GenerateBoard()
{
    int buttonNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; j++)
        {
            GameObject button = Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(xAxis, yAxis, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            button.transform.SetParent(newParent);

            boardButtons[buttonNumber] = button; //.GetComponentInChildren<Button>()
            yAxis += 300;
        }
        yAxis = 0;
        xAxis += 300;
    }
}
```

tilePrefab is the Button prefab, newParent is the canvas. This works for the most part, but when I try to add the created buttons to a list or an button[] array, there is a conflict. Because even though my tilePrefab is a ui button obect, generating it like this means that "button" is a GameObject.

How can i fix that so that i can create a list or an button[] array and successfully store the newly created button in that list/array? I tried "public BoardPiece tilePrefab" or "public Button tilePrefab", but then the Instantiate doesn't work. (BoardPiece is the name of the Prefab)

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because even though my tilePrefab is a ui button obect

The tilePrefab is a GameObject that has a Button Component attached, they are two different things that seem to be causing confusion. I'd suggest renaming `GameObject Button` to `GOButton` to make it clear that it is a `GameOject` and not a `Button`.

If you want to store a list of Button, you have to make sure you are adding a Button, in order to do this, I'd suggest you create a list of Buttons:

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
```

Then every time you instantiate the `GOButton`, you then add the `Button` Component to your list:

```
buttonList.Add(GOButton.GetComponent<Button>());
```

This way you then have a list of Buttons that you can loop and handle how you please:

```
foreach (Button button in buttonList)
{
   //change button state here
}
```

Comment: Easier way is to have your tilePrefab as a Button, and you can then instantiate it as a button, instead of calling GetComponent on it

Comment: @reecemcg
Thanks, that helped. It works to an extent. 
The Problem that I have now ist that the following call to an method from a script that the prefab button has as a component no longer works. Beforehand, the buttonList was a list of the text child of the manually created buttons.


buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<BoardPiece>().SetGameControllerReference(this);


Just calling the method directly on buttonList[i] does not work either. How do I reference to a method, that's from a script added to the prefab used to create the buttons?

Comment: @Jichael
How would I create the tilePrefab as Button? I created the actual prefab from a ui button. Or do you mean in the script as "Button tilePrefab" instead of "GameObject tilePrefab"? Because that led to Instatiate() not working.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the change you made affected what you are saying, are they related? Or is it a separate issue?

Comment: Wait I think I know what you mean: buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<BoardPiece>()… that's because you can't get a component of a component, you will have to do buttonList[i].gameobject.GetComponentInParent<BoardPiece>()... off the top of my head that should be fine.

Comment: @reecemcg
They were indirectly related. Beforehand, I manually created buttons in my scene and dragged the text children of those buttons into the buttonList (because in the earlier version I only changed the text children of the buttons). Now that I create the buttons in my script, I wanted to rectify that questionable design decision an make the list a list of buttons. That cause the mentioned method to stop working. But I got a tip from Reddit to change it to the following:
buttonList[i].GetComponent<BoardPiece>().SetGameControllerReference(this);
Which worked as intended.

Comment: So my issue is now completely resolved. Thanks for the help.